# Access Docker volume Mountpoint with Docker for Mac

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker for mac and I want to find where are the volume created by Docker.

```sh
# Create volume
docker volume create --name volume-name

# Create container binding this volume
docker run -dti -v volume-name:/data --name deb debian:jessie

# Create a file in container:/data
docker exec -ti deb touch /data/test.txt

# Find the Mountpoint
docker volume inspect volume-name
# Get :
# [
#     {
#         "Name": "volume-name",
#         "Driver": "local",
#         "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/volume-name/_data",
#         "Labels": {},
#         "Scope": "local"
#     }
# ]
```

When I am using Docker on Linux, I can run

```
ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/volume-name/_data
```

and see the `test.txt` file

But, on macOs I don't know where I can find this Mountpoint.

I found this post ([Docker volume mount doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830064/docker-volume-mount-doesnt-exist)) but the author seems to use boot2docker and I'm not.

```
docker-machine ssh default
# Host does not exist: "default"
```

Can someone help me to find this Mountpoint on macOs using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found the solution to **get access of the linux virtual machine using docker for mac**

```
sudo screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/volume-name/_data
mv test.txt /Users/path/to/destination
```

By default some directories are shared (/Users, /Volumes, ...), Then I can move my data volume directory to my mac from the vm.

Comment: not sure since which version of docker for mac, but since i'm running version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 I need to do `sudo screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, there's no tty file.