# Is there a way to determine the size of a docker volume on my macOS machine?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-volume

I'm aware of `docker volume ls` and `docker inspect -s`, but the former doesn't show size info and the latter, even though it has a `--size` option, ignores it for volumes.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This:

```
docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' volumeNameHere
```

will return the mount point of the volume on your host. So, to get the size, it's just a matter of doing:

```
du -sh $(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' volumeNameHere)
```

Comment: This is weird. When I run `docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' my-volume-id` it returns `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-volume-id/_data`, but `du -sh $(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' my-volume-id)` returns `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Are you on ios, on docker-machine?

Comment: I'm on MacOS, which is the machine running docker.

Comment: You are running docker in a VM then, which contains the volume in question. I'm not too sure about docker desktop, but it's just a matter of ssh into that vm and then run that command.

Comment: No, I'm not using a VM. My containers are running on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Federkun. I figured out the details of ssh'ing into the virtual machine (I didn't even know it existed) and added them to another answer to this question.

Comment: nice, I didn't know until now how you could ssh into docker vm on ios, glad to have that answered as well

Comment: On MacOS, I did this that worked:
`docker run --rm -v /:/vm-root alpine du -sH /vm-root/$(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' volumeNameHere)`

Comment: if you use Docker Desktop, you use a VM. so the files of the volume are inside the VM, not in the macOS host machine.

Answer (score 74):

You can use:

```
docker system df -v
```

More info at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by the answer of @MikeWu,
one can see the size of Docker Volumes with:

```
docker system df -v
```

but one has to scroll around a bit to find the section `Local Volumes space usage:`.
Using a piped `sed` command like:

```
docker system df -v | sed -n '/VOLUME NAME/,/^ *$/p'
```

will help to improve the readability and reduce the output to the section of interest - by printing only from `VOLUME NAME` until first empty line.

Comment: This is excellent and, instead of the accepted answer showing for a particular volume, this shows it for all volumes! Perfect for pre-pruning review.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Federkun's answer:

```
docker run --rm -v /:/vm-root alpine du -sH /vm-root/$(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' volumeNameHere)
```

Answer (score 3):

The first step of Federkun's answer worked for me and it returned something like this:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/f4678f...b87/_data
```

But when I tried

```
du -sh $(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' volumeNameHere)
```

it returned a

```
du: /var/lib/docker/volumes/f4678f...b87/_data: No such file or directory
```

It turns out Docker works differently on macOS. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41281658/1812322), before I can run the `du -sh` command I must first `screen` into the docker virtual machine used by MacOS. You can do so by running

```
sudo screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

and then you can run

```
du -sh /var/lib/docker/volumes/f4678f...
```

to finally get the volume size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Go templates to format the [DiskUsageContext](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/formatter/disk_usage.go):

```
docker system df --verbose --format '{{ range .Volumes }}{{ .Name }} {{ .Size }}\n{{ end }}'
```

And if you want to check for a specific volume, and convert the human-readable values back to bytes, you can use `awk`:

```
docker system df --verbose --format '{{ range .Volumes }}{{ .Name }} {{ .Size }}\n{{ end }}' | awk -v "volume_name=VOLUME_NAME"  'BEGIN { sizes["k"] = 1024; sizes["M"] = 1024^2; sizes["G"] = 1024^3; sizes[""] = 1; } match($0, "^" volume_name " ([0-9.]+)([kMG]?)B$", arr) { printf("%d\n", arr[1] * sizes[arr[2]]); }'
```