# How to allow native tools on OSX to access files in a docker volume

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

Our development environment uses a VSCode dev container. Due to file system performance in Docker on OSX we're checking out all of our code into a mounted volume instead of mounting a path on the host.

This works well and the performance is acceptable but it's not possible to use native tools outside of VSCode.

For example I would like to use the electron based Cypress app to develop browser tests or Beyond Compare as my diff tool but they obviously can't access the source code inside the docker volume.

Is it possible to mount a docker volume onto the host system?

Comment: It's not, especially on MacOS.  My typical workflow is to do day-to-day development without involving containers at all, and then build an image for integration testing and deployment, with no volumes involved at all.

Comment: [Access Docker volume Mountpoint with Docker for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273514/access-docker-volume-mountpoint-with-docker-for-mac) for example has a recipe for getting into the hidden Linux VM, and from there you could directly see the named-volume files, but it'd be hard to tie that back into your IDE.